# Is there a way to know if a function is returning to a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I'd like to know if there is a way in PHP to know if a function just being called is going to return something to a variable (or not).

For example, is there a way to know when this happens:

1. `$foo = bar();` // yes it will return to a variable
2. `bar();` // no, it won't return to a variable

It'd be best if there's a way to know that within the bar() function. If nothing like this exists - is it possible to implement?

I don't currently need to do this, but a simple use case is:

```
class Model() {
    private $foo = 0;

    function bar() {
        $foo += 100;

        if(returnsToVariable) // <====
            return $foo;
    }
}
```

So it can be used to get an immediate value of $foo (and yeah I know I could/haveto use a setter, this is just an illustrative example).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t see what this would be useful for. Whether or not the `bar` method in your example returns anything, doesn’t affect what else goes on inside the method. And no, there is no simple way to determine this. A function/method does not “return to a variable”, it just gets called without knowing anything about the surrounding script. You could however just pass a parameter that tells the function whether or not it should return something.

Comment: Function should not bother about what is going to happen outside of it. You can always return value, if it is not assgined or used anywhere no harm done.

Comment: The use case is invalid. There is quite literally NEVER a use case for what you mentioned. And as others said, function doesn't care whether it "returns to a variable". Function does its job and returns, which is optional. That's all. What you can do, as an eager developer, is create a wrapper around the function call and ensure that the result is always stored in a variable.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the insightful answers. I was mostly asking a theoretical question regarding if PHP functions have any environment awareness. @Justinas' answer is what I'm using at the moment, I was just curious if I could in any way simplify my code and omit that.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this function in appropriate way. When you set `returnToVariable` constant, than expect something to be returned, else, there is no returned value and your `$foo = bar()` will be `NULL`.

```
class Model() {
    private $foo = 0;

    function bar($return = false) {
        $this->foo += 100;

        if($return)
            return $this->foo;
    }
}


$model = new Model();
$model->bar(); //$model->foo == 100
$foo = $model->bar(true); //$model->foo == $foo == 200
$foo = $model->bar(); //$model->foo == 200; $foo == null;
$model->bar(true); //$model->foo == 300; $foo == null;
```